# Android SQLite: Fast insert/update

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my Android application I am using compiled statements to be able to insert rows quickly:

```
insert = db.compileStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO foo (id, aaa, bbb, ccc) " +
                    "VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
```

This works correctly and quite fast. However when there is already `foo` with `id`, I am receiving following exception:

```
column id is not unique (code 19)
```

What would be a correct way for overwriting existing row?

Comment: If you want to overwrite it, use the `UPDATE`-statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What would be a correct way for overwriting existing row?

Specify a [conflict resolution strategy](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html), such as

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO foo ...
```

If the insert would result in a conflict, the conflicting row(s) are first deleted and then the new row is inserted.

Comment: This would work, but just be careful with it!  Make absolutely sure it's what you need for your requirements.  Remember, this "deletes" the row first if it exists then replaces it with the new row.  This is NOT the same as a row update.  If you're needing to actually update the row but not remove it, then you can first do a simple query against the table to determine if it exists, then perform an update if it does, otherwise do an insert.